# grub-install looking for /,

Tags: grub2

Installing regular ubuntu updates via software updater gives me the following error:

grub-install: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /,.  Check your device.map.

I have no idea why it is looking for a drive mounted on "/,", but it doesn't exist.

Before fixing this, I'd like to know if killing software updater will screw up my boot.

Comment: Have you done `sudo update-grub` from your terminal command line?  This will sometimes fix the problem